# FONT FAMILY is not working in System Print

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My font family which is **ARIAL NARROW** is not working when i enable the browser print, when on screen it is good but its in print preview it will become **TIMES NEW ROMAN**.

Sample code, this style css is inside my **dvContainer**

```
<div id="dvContainer" class="dvContainer">
 <style type="text/css" media="all">
                            @page 
                              {
                                  size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
                                  margin: 20mm 20mm 20mm 20mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
                                  font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif !important;
                              }

                              html
                              {
                                background-color: #FFFFFF; 
                                margin: 0px;  /* this affects the margin on the html before sending to printer */
                              }
                              .dvContainer p li ol { 
                                font-family: "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif !important;
                                color: #000;
                                font-size: 9px !important;
                              }

                              table {
                                cellpadding: 1;
                              }
                              .pagebreak { page-break-before: always; } /* page-break-after works, as well */
                          </style>
```

Which will be called by this function:

```
$("#btnPrint").live("click", function () {
        var divContents = $("#dvContainer").html();
        var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=600,width=1000');
        printWindow.document.writeln('<!DOCTYPE html>');
        printWindow.document.writeln('<html><head><title></title>');
        printWindow.document.writeln('</head><body>');
        printWindow.document.writeln(divContents);
        printWindow.document.writeln('</body></html>');
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.print();
    });
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
[image]

**OUTPUT FROM PRINT PREVIEW** 
[image]

Really need help

Comment: Try moving the font rule to the `html` rule set and see if that works.

Comment: I copied your code and it worked fine for me. I am on Chrome 78 - MacOS Catalina. It may be an OS or browser specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

This way, you can provide different CSS style of the same elements for different media, such as "print" and "screen":

```css
@media print {
   body { font-size: 10pt }
 }
 @media screen {
   body { font-size: 13px }
 }
 @media screen, print {
   body { line-height: 1.2 }
 }
```